# Batch converting xls to csv via parallel processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I am batch converting 30 gb xls files to csv on a regular basis. To reduce the time how should I use parallel processing on an i5 windows pc. (Its current taking me 3 hours for 30 GB conversion). I am a newbie

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

excel_files = glob.glob(r'filepath\*.xls') 

for excel in excel_files:

    out = excel.split('.')[0] +'.csv'


    df = pd.read_excel(excel) # if only the first sheet is needed.


    df.to_csv(out)
```

## Code with multiprocessing is now working and but is taking more time (3 times more!) than the above code. Read and found that it might be due to the Input Output operations. Can we speed it up?

```
import multiprocessing 
import glob
import pandas as pd
excel_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Test\*.xls') # the path where your files are
counter= 0
def multi():
    for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0] +'.csv'

    df = pd.read_excel(excel) # if only the first sheet is needed.

    df.to_csv(out)

    return

if __name__ =='__main__':
#freeze_support()
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #num_cores=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    #print(num_cores)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    result= pool.map(multi,excel_files,8)
```

Comment: have you tried multi processing library of python ?

Comment: I did try the multiprocessing and concurrent.futures libraries. However couldn't get them to work. Get the following error "Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.
            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable."

Comment: what is the error in the above multi processing code also move the last two lines inside the main !

Comment: There are couple problems here. It's to broad for SO, setup a [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com).

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain Thanks. it helped and started working, but is taking even longer!